# change the value of a qantity field with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have form with multiple qty fields, I'd like to add the qty but pressing the add button and subtract the qty by pressing a minus button, I got it working for one but I can not make it work for multiple qty fields,I have 24 qty fields, any help would appreciate it.

```
<form>
    <input name="minus1" type="button" class="button" id="minus1" value=" - " />
    <input name="textfield1" type="text" id="textfield1" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
    <input name="add1" type="button" class="button" id="add1" value=" + " />

    <input name="minus2" type="button" class="button" id="minus2" value=" - " />
    <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
    <input name="add2" type="button" class="button" id="add2" value=" + " />

    ......
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#add1").click(function () {
            var newQty = +($("#textfield1").val()) + 1;
            $("#textfield1").val(newQty);
        });

        $("#minus1").click(function () {
            var newQty = +($("#textfield1").val()) - 1;
            if (newQty < 0) newQty = 0;
            $("#textfield1").val(newQty);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Look into the jQuery each() function.  What fields are you trying to add/subtract together?  Any random combination of any random couple fields?  Or all together?

Comment: Dont think he wants to add them all up, just apply the same functionality to each set of inputs

Comment: (re duplicate: please update this question; don't re-ask it)

Comment: some of the answers given don't work and some just add/subtract one field only, I've added a class to all textfields but it doesn't work.
any more ideas would be appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

Try to assign classes to the inputs. Then you do not have to repeat the script x(24) times

```
 <input name="minus1" type="button" class="button minus" value=" - " />
 <input name="textfield1" type="text" class="text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
 <input name="add2" type="button" class="button add" value=" + " />

 <input name="minus2" type="button" class="button minus" value=" - " />
 <input name="textfield2" type="text" class="text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
 <input name="add2" type="button" class="button add"  value=" + " />
```

js

//N.B need to ensure input is numerical also

```
$('input.add').live('click', function(){

    var $textInput = $(this).prev();
    $textInput.val( $textInput.val() + 1 );

});

$('input.minus').live('click', function(){

    var $textInput = $(this).next();
    var newQty = $textInput.val() - 1;
    newQty > 0 ? $textInput.val(newQty) : $textInput.val(0)

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not try something like this:

```
<form>
  <input name="textfield1" type="text" class="quantity" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
  <input name="textfield2" type="text" class="quantity" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
  <input name="textfield3" type="text" class="quantity" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
  ...
  <input name="textfieldn" type="text" class="quantity" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
</form>
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.quantity').each(function() {
    $field = $(this);
    $field.before(
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').val(' - ').bind('click', function() {
        var newVal = parseInt($field.val()) - 1;
        if (newVal < 0)
          newVal = 0;
        $field.val(newVal);
      })
    );
    $field.after(
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').val(' + ').bind('click', function() {
        var newVal = parseInt($field.val()) + 1;
        if (newVal < 0)
          newVal = 0;
        $field.val(newVal);
      })
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Neat solution that also saves a load of typing - thereby reducing the chance of errors.

Comment: thanks for the reply, my coding is already done, I need to make it work,the code above adds extra buttons to only one of the field, why is that? anymore solutions please.

Comment: As belugabob pointed out, it reduces a lot of typing and thus the chance of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I assume he wants to group the buttons so that one minus/plus button works on one field etc.

Well, first I'd make the id into classes and group the elements in HTML using the fieldset:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input name="minus1" type="button" class="button minus" value=" - " />
    <input name="textfield1" type="text" class="valfield" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
    <input name="add1" type="button" class="button add" value=" + " />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input name="minus2" type="button" class="button minus" value=" - " />
    <input name="textfield2" type="text" class="valfield" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
    <input name="add2" type="button" class="button add" value=" + " />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then I'd make the jquery work with siblings:

```
$(function()
{
  $(".add").click(function(){
    var newQty =+($(this).siblings(".valfield").val()) + 1;
    $(this).siblings(".valfield").val(newQty);
  });

  $(".minus").click(function(){
    var newQty = +($(this).siblings(".valfield").val()) - 1;
    if(newQty < 0)newQty = 0;
    $(this).siblings(".valfield").val(newQty);
  });
});
```

Hopefully what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

try parseInt...

```
var newQty = parseInt($("#textfield1").val()) + 1;
```

ok actually that has nothing to do with your problem... :( sorry you need to use a loop

### Step 1

add a class to each textfield like so

```
<input class="incremental_text_field" name="textfield1" type="text" id="textfield1" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
```

### Step 2

just add this loop to your DOM-ready function (based on your existing code)

```
$(".incremental_text_field").each(function() {
    field_number = $(this).attr("id").replace("textfield", "");

    $("#add" + field_number).click(function(){
        var newQty = +($("#textfield" + field_number).val()) + 1;
        $("#textfield" + field_number).val(newQty);
    });

    $("#minus" + field_number).click(function(){
        var newQty = +($("#textfield" + field_number).val()) - 1;
        if(newQty < 0) newQty = 0;
        $("#textfield" + field_number).val(newQty);
    });
});
```